# Linux Command Line List Files

Tags: linux, command-line

First and foremost, I would like to say thank you in advanced for anybody that takes time out of there day to help me with this problem I am having.  So, I am in this class and it's an assignment that want me to list specific files through Linux command line. I believed I was able to do it a few times and now I'm just not getting the assignment incorrect. I am very new in learning Linux so please forgive me if this very basic.  I have attached below exactly what the assignment wants me to do.

List down only the Sonnet files (files that have the name Sonnet appearing in them).

List down Shakespeare's Sonnets (files which start with the name Shakespeare_Sonnet)

what command would get me to do this correctly?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please note that we do not entertain homework questions on this site for a variety of reasons. You should be using the resources your professor has provided to learn this answer.

Comment: This isn’t homework I am in self paced course on my own

Comment: I don’t have a professor to report too

Comment: Then level 2: You'll need to give us more info. What have you tried? What were the results? How did you results differ from the expectation? What research have you done regarding this and what didn't you understand?

Comment: I will not give you the answer, but I will tell you that you need a command to list files and that command will receive a parameter to tell the command what to filter out/in.    Read [this](https://www.warp.dev/terminus/linux-wildcards) it should have been part of your course materials (official course or not).  Use that article to do further research if need be.

Comment: Try googling for "Linux Wildcards" for example here is a reasonable article with some similar things to what you are trying to do: https://www.warp.dev/terminus/linux-wildcards